# Prove equality of angles in parallelogram

Tags: geometry

In a parallelogram $ABCD$,  $P$ is a point inside the parallelogram such that $\angle APB + \angle CPD=180$. Prove that $\angle PDC=\angle PBC$.

Comment: Tell us about your workings.

Comment: I am not getting from where to start.

Comment: How are the vertices labelled?They don't seem to follow any convention.

Comment: Did you use propeties of the parallelogram: $180 = \angle DCB + \angle CBA$ plus the equalities with triangles, etc. ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3232554/parallelogram-and-a-point